# Azure stop/start: How to loop through VM list and check status

Tags: bash, azure, automation, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I am trying to start/shut down VMs in parallel while also checking the powerstate to make sure it is either running/deallocated. Currently, my script waits on each VM to complete its operation before moving to the next VM. I want to be able to start/stop, check powerstate, move to the next one, check powerstate again and keep looping till all conditions are met.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VM_IDS="$(az resource list --tag Nonessential=Yes --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'].{VM:name, RG:resourceGroup}" -o tsv >> vm.txt)"

cat vm.txt

  if [[ "${OPTIONS}" == "stop" ]]; then
    while read VM RG; do
      timeout 10s az vm deallocate -g $RG -n $VM --no-wait
      #PS=$(az vm show -g $RG -n $VM --show-details --query powerState -o tsv | tr -d '"')
      echo "$VM is shutting down & deallocating..."

      while [[ `az vm show -g $RG -n $VM --show-details --query powerState` != "VM deallocated" ]]; do
          sleep 5
          PS=`az vm show -g $RG -n $VM --show-details --query powerState -o tsv | tr -d '"'`
          if [[ "${PS}" == "VM deallocated" ]]; then
              echo "$VM has deallocated successfully..."
              echo "--------------------------------------------------"
              echo
              break
          else
              echo "$VM is still deallocating..."

          fi
      done
    done <vm.txt
  elif [[ "${OPTIONS}" == "start" ]]; then
    while read VM RG; do
      timeout 10s az vm start -g $RG -n $VM --no-wait
      #PS=$(az vm show -g $RG -n $VM --show-details --query powerState -o tsv | tr -d '"')
      echo "$VM is starting..."

      while [[ `az vm show -g $RG -n $VM --show-details --query powerState` != "VM running" ]]; do
          sleep 5
          PS=`az vm show -g $RG -n $VM --show-details --query powerState -o tsv | tr -d '"'`
          if [[ "${PS}" == "VM running" ]]; then
              echo "$VM has started successfully..."
              echo "--------------------------------------------------"
              echo
              break
          else
              echo "$VM is still starting..."

          fi
      done
    done <vm.txt
  else
        echo "Try again..."
        exit 1
  fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Have you considered using GNU `parallel` ? You might need to refactor your code a little, but should do the trick.

Comment: You can use the CLI command `az vm get-instance-view --name VMName --resource-group resourceGroupName --query instanceView.statuses[1] --output table` to get the power state of the VM.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT I am able to get the powerstate using `az vm show -g $RG -n $VM -d --query powerState`. However, I want to loop the VM list to check if the Status is either running or deallocated.

Eg: vm1 is starting
      Vm2 is starting
      Vm1 is still starting...
      Vm2 is still starting...
      Vm1 has started...
      Vm2 has started..

Comment: @bonafideaf It seems if you want to do that you just can use a loop language as you posted. There is no ready command for that on Azure.